# Creating Conditional Statement Based On Page URL

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using Mapquests gps lookup API and Wordpress, so am applying the same map.js functions to populate longitude, latitude and address for fields existing on completely different pages of the same site. For example, this is what I have so far (latitude example only) and can ONLY get the first statement to work, while others don't on the other pages, that is, populating field with the value.

Better yet, is there a better way, besides GetElementById to fill these form ids that exist on different pages? It fails if the value is null, since it looks for the ID that isn't on the page...

Found this example: [Javascript match part of url, if statement based on result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988327/javascript-match-part-of-url-if-statement-based-on-result)

JS

```
var str = "http://wordpressite.com/soco-app/forms/lights-out/report-vegetation-growth-web/report-vegetation-growth-iphone/"
if (str.indexOf("http://wordpressite.com/soco-app/forms/lights-out") === 0) {
document.getElementById("input_1_11").value = latitude;
} else if (str.indexOf("http://wordpressite.com/soco-app/forms/report-vegetation-growth-web") === 0) {
document.getElementById("input_2_6").value = latitude;
} else if (str.indexOf("http://wordpressite.com/soco-app/forms/report-vegetation-growth-iphone") === 0) {
document.getElementById("input_3_6").value = latitude;
}
```

HTML for Page 1 - lights-out

```
<li id='field_1_11' class='gfield     gform_hidden' ><input name='input_11' id='input_1_11' type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' value='' /></li><li id='field_1_12' class='gfield     gform_hidden' ><input name='input_12' id='input_1_12' type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' value='' /></li><li id='field_1_13' class='gfield     gform_hidden' ><input name='input_13' id='input_1_13' type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' value='' /></li>
```

HTML for Page 2 - report-vegetation-growth-web

```
<li id='field_2_6' class='gfield     gform_hidden' ><input name='input_6' id='input_2_6' type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' value='' /></li><li id='field_2_7' class='gfield     gform_hidden' ><input name='input_7' id='input_2_7' type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' value='' /></li><li id='field_2_8' class='gfield     gform_hidden' ><input name='input_8' id='input_2_8' type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' value='' /></li>
```

That's the gist.... I am using gravity forms plugin, but the IDs, once the fields are created, are static unless I delete a field.

Comment: What is the problem are you facing, as the code seems to be right.

Comment: The problem is that if ID doesn't exist he gets error. Cache the element in variable, then check if exists; if so set value.

Comment: the fields are simply not populating on the other pages :(

Comment: Can you show us the HTML too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
var str = window.location.pathname; // get the current URL;
var el; // cache element;
if(str.indexOf('lights-out') > -1) {
    el = document.getElementById("input_1_11");
} else if(str.indexOf('growth-web') > -1) {
    el = document.getElementById("input_2_6");
} else if(str.indexOf('growth-iphone') > -1) {
    el = document.getElementById("input_3_6");
}

if(el)
    el.value = latitude;
```

Comment: Good way of thinking. Even this *might* throw an error while setting. Lets see if this works.

Comment: Didn't work... I even changed your mistype of "srt" to str and added a missing bracket for the opening if statement. Had my hopes up haha

Comment: changing the `if` statement to `if(el!=null)` would prevent errors, if any.

Comment: @jflay what errors are you getting exactly? (and fixed the typos and missing bracket and = . Damn it's late :p

Comment: I'm not even getting any errors, which is annoying. I am getting blank values for the fields when my js code I know works, but only if I use one ElementById at a time. If I only use the one javascript ElementByID the field populates as it should, but when I add more to the mix it doesn't... and I can't add all three side by side because I will get "Timestamp: 5/24/13 12:04:36 AM
Error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
Source File: http://asset.com/soco-app/forms/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/map.js
Line: 26"

Comment: Now getting: Timestamp: 5/24/13 12:17:41 AM
Error: TypeError: str.indexOf is not a function
Source File: http://asset.com/soco-app/forms/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/map.js
Line: 37

Comment: can you check if the `if` is testing true to any of those cases? a simple `console.log('page:' + window.location, 'element: '+el)` would help you find the root of the problem. if it's not getting into any of the `if` blocks, then the problem is on the test.

Comment: change `var str = window.location` to `var str = window.location.pathname`

Comment: By Jov! I think the path name did it, man. Very cool! The problem with my code above was that it kept reading the first argument no matter the page and would throw the type error "can't return value of null." Thanks heaps!